# Persist newly calculated value in delta lake - Databricks operation MERGE fails

Tags: python, pyspark, merge, azure-databricks, delta-lake

**Situation description**

I'm working with Databricks on Azure and perform an MERGE operation. I'm loading the initial delta table *dt* with `spark.read.format("delta").option('MergeSchema',True).load(link)` from my delta lake. This delta table has about 12k rows, about 6k columns, containing mostly arrays with, in average, 4 entries, and has a size of about 250MB. Each row is identified uniquely with an ID, it also contains a boolean column *metadata#FTA*. Now, I calculate a boolean quantity for about 400 rows (those who have *null* in the *metadata#FTA* column) out of this datatable. What I want to do next is to merge the calculated values into the delta table and make them persistent in the delta lake. This is an recurring operation that calculates a boolean based on other entries of the same row - this result should be stored back to the delta table.

**My approach**

I'm using this operation (*tgt* contains the calculated boolean as *metadata#FTA* and the unique ID as UID):

```
df_org=DeltaTable.forPath(spark,link)
df_org.alias('tgt') \
  .merge(
    source=ftas.alias('update'),
    condition='"update.UID" = "tgt.metadata#uniqueid"'
  ) \
  .whenMatchedUpdate(
  set={
    'metadata#FTA': 'update.`metadata#FTA`'
  }
  ) \
  .execute()
```

The output is

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 73.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 73.0 (TID 791) (10.11.234.198 executor 9): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with code 50
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 73.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 73.0 (TID 791) (10.11.234.198 executor 9): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Command exited with code 50
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3480)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3412)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3401)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3401)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1467)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1467)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1467)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3638)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3626)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$runJob$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1213)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1201)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2841)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$runSparkJobs$1(Collector.scala:338)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$collect$1(Collector.scala:366)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$computeResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:553)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.collectResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.computeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:426)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeCollectResult$1(SparkPlan.scala:504)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3726)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectResult$1(Dataset.scala:3717)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$3(Dataset.scala:4642)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1038)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4640)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3716)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:267)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:101)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.generateTableResult(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:744)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal.computeListResultsItem(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:1053)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal$JupyterEntryPoint.addCustomDisplayData(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:397)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Here is the summary of the compute cluster I'm using:

[image]

**Questions**

- Why does this operation fail? The amount of data is quite limited compared to the compute cluster.
- What's best practice when adding new calculations for a subset of rows for one column to a delta table stored in a delta lake?

**What else I have tried**

In my initial approach, I made the calculation the same way but then I loaded the already calculated boolean from the initial delta table, made an union with the new calculated values, joined these two delta tables together, and stored them in the delta lake with

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema","true").format("delta").saveAsTable(link)
```

This operation did not succeed as well.

Comment: please put stacktrace as text, not as image